# Can I use SUMPRODUCT to accomplish this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to sum a range based on if a value is in a column and one of a set of values is in another column, or vice versa.
e.g. I have The following table:

```
A     B      C      D  
M     C      C      1
F     C      C      2
S     N      C      3
S     N      N      4
M     -      C      5
N     C      C      6
M     C      N      7
```

If (Column A contains "M" or "S") AND ((Column B contains "C" AND Column C Contains "C" Or "N" Or "-") OR (Column C contains "C" AND Column B Contains "C" Or "N" Or "-")) Then Sum column D

So from my table my results would be 
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A10,{"M","S"},0)*MATCH(B2:B10&"^"&C2:C10,{"C^C","C^N","C^-","N^C","-^C"},0))+0,D2:D10)`

`MATCH` is used to check for both valid possibilities in column A and then all 5 possibilities for concatenated columns B and C - if those conditions are met then column D will be summed. Extend column ranges as required but preferably don't use whole columns

.....or shorter with `SUMIFS` like this:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,{"M";"S"},B:B,{"C","C","C","N","-"},C:C,{"C","N","-","C","C"}))`

For that version you **can** use whole columns with no loss of efficiency.

Note that in this version all the separators in the array constants are commas **EXCEPT** for the semi-colon in {"M";"S"} which needs to be that way

[image]

Comment: That SUM(SUMIFS works nicely. Thank you very much. I just need to do some learning on the intricacies of some of these nice Excel Formulas. I tried to upvote this answer, but am too new.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a fifth column with a condition for the current line returning the value in `D` if all conditions are true or `0` otherwise.

```
=Iif(AND(Or($A1 = "M", $A1 = "S"),OR(AND($B1 = "C",Or($C1 = "C",$C1 = "N",$C1 = "-")), AND($C1 = "C",OR($B1 = "C",$B1 = "N",$B1 = "-")))),$D1,0)
```

Then in a cell somewhere write `=sum($E:$E)`. With your example, I get 16, as intended.

Comment: I was hoping for some awesome formula to do the whole thing from a different sheet without using an extra column, but that can work for now.